# How to display an error message upon page load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

If a user gets redirected back to the same page because of some condition that I check for, I want to display a small error message at the top of the page saying why.  For example, I have 2 buttons at the bottom of my application: 1 to reload the page so they can enter in more information, and the other to move on to the next page.  Before they can ever move on, they need to have entered something in.  If they don't enter something, then I want to reload the page and give them an error message saying "please enter blah."  I was thinking something like

```
ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Please enter blah."
```

but how do I make sure this is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output that error message by putting `@ViewBag.ErrorMessage` in your view. You could even put it in your _Layout and reuse the concept for any page you want.

For example, you could open up `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` and add the code like this:

```
<body>

    @ViewBag.ErrorMessage

</body>
```

You can then set the error message in any controller action and it will always be displayed in the same spot.

Don't worry if you don't set an error message. The ViewBag/ViewData don't mind null values; it simply won't be displayed.